# How do I fetch data from API in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, request

I'm trying to set up a Flask API Server from which I can data from local database via an ongoing HTTP Request to another database.

In the local code, I run a thread that is running and updating the local DB every 1 minute.

```py
app = Flask(__name__)

cached_event_log = None
@app.route('/event_log', methods=['GET'])
def get_event_log():
    if cached_event_log != None and .get_latest_event_time == cached_event_log[-1]:
        return jsonify(cached_event_log)
    #MAKE CONNECTION TO DB AND GET THE DATA
    return jsonify(event_log)

if(__name__ == '__main__'):
    app.run(Debug=True)
```

I'm struggling to find a "standard" way to set up A request.

Any opinion would be highly appreciated- Thank you,

Comment: Have a look at Flask-APScheduler
https://github.com/viniciuschiele/flask-apscheduler This lets you do backend scheduled tasks (such as sampling something every 5 minutes) as well as reactive API calls.

Comment: I keep coming back to this question, but despite the potential inefficiency what assuming non-distributed server environment, in which just physical wiring up servers and API Server would work(i.e. ongoing HTTP Request), how would I go about it, do you have any clue by any chance? Thanks for your time for the response; I'm grateful. @dwgaon

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. How to initiate a http request? I would highly recommend looking at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up a cron job to run a script at a specified interval

Or use something like Advanced Python Scheduler
https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/

Advanced Python Scheduler support in Flask
https://github.com/viniciuschiele/flask-apscheduler

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I set up cron jobs with short python scripts to fetch twitter data every day- I forgot that even existed. Thank you- I was looking more into how I could set up an ongoing connection between a local DB and the Server, or that there is no way for such and I have to make 'reactive' calls every time I need the data from DB.